# error 403 on nodejs when running .js file

Tags: javascript

help pls, I am trying to do a POST on my api but I am getting error 403, I read many topics but still not resolved my problem. 
I am running my js file on nodejs prompt using comand: node myfilename.js to compile and getting this error. below is my code. I was supposed to get a json file back from the site I am trying to consume.

```
var app = require('./config/customs-express')();
var unirest = require('unirest');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var qs     = require('querystring');

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Server running door 3000');
});

var MB_TAPI_ID  = 'xxx';
var REQUEST_HOST = 'https://www.xxxx.net';
var REQUEST_PATH = '/tapi/v3';
var MB_TAPI_SECRET = 'xxx';

var tapi_nonce = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

var tapi_method = 'list_orders';

var params = (tapi_method, tapi_nonce);

var params_string = ((REQUEST_PATH) + '?' + (params));

var tapi_mac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', MB_TAPI_SECRET)
               .update(tapi_method + ':' + MB_TAPI_SECRET + ':' +         
tapi_nonce)
               .digest('hex');

                unirest.post(REQUEST_HOST)
  .headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
  .headers({'Key': MB_TAPI_ID})
  .headers({'Sign': tapi_mac})
  .send(qs.stringify({'method': tapi_method, 'tonce': tapi_nonce}))
  .send(qs.stringify(params_string))
  .end(function (response) {
    console.log(response.body);
});
var app = require('./config/customs-express')();
var unirest = require('unirest');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var qs     = require('querystring');

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Server running door 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

403 means forbidden. The API is telling you "no."

If this works when you visit the page, it probably means they are using cookies. If that is the case, first hit the login page, get a cookie, then send the login request with the cookie. [Superagent can do this](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#preserving-cookies), for example.

Comment: hi. thanks, this might help. so, do I just need to add this code to my code?                                                                                                             const agent = request.agent();
agent
  .post('/login')
  .then(() => {
    return agent.get('/cookied-page');
  });

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know what site you are trying to scrape. Can you describe how you would get to the info you want in the browser?

Comment: I feel like I am htting a wall here, so much work to make the code to work and complie and my request is not getting through.

Comment: <title>403 Forbidden</title>
<body>
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p><small>More information is available with DEBUG=True.</small></p>

Comment: Have you tried setting debug to true, as it suggests? Also, your code doesn't compile, it's interpreted

Comment: Do you know Java? They have a Java client https://github.com/MercadoBitcoin/mb-api-client-java

Comment: hi Sam, thanks for your help. I dont know how to setup debug for true but I will look for it. As in regards to their java client, I know java and all, I downloaded the code into eclipse but I couldnt get my head around it, meaning = I have no idea where to start with that code on github. haha. that is why I tried using nodejs. thanks